# Exactly when is a linear first-order differential equation separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The standard form of a linear firs-order DE is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x) y = Q(x)$$

I think the equation is separable if and only if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are constants, but I'm not sure. (Haven't found any counterexamples but also can't seem to prove it.) Can anyone confirm or deny that this is correct?

Comment: For $P=0$ for any $Q$ The DE is separable.

Answer (score 1):

For $P=0$ and for any $Q$ The DE is separable.
You have also the case when $P=\lambda Q$
Where $\lambda$ is a constant, then it's also separable:
$$y' + P(x) y = Q(x)$$
$$y' + \lambda Q(x)y = Q(x)$$
$$y'=Q(x)(1-\lambda y)$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{1-\lambda y}=Q(x)dx$$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Combining Pierre's answer gives these three rules: if both P and Q are constant, or if at least one of them is $0$, or if P=Q, then the equation is separable. Is this now correct in general?

Comment: $P=cQ$ where $c$ is a constant is also separable @JamesRonald

Comment: Ah okay, so it's: 1. if both P and Q are constant, or 2. if at least one of them is $0$, or 3. if $\exists c\in R$ such that P=cQ, then the equation is separable.

Comment: In these cases it's separable yes  @JamesRonald

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion is not true. For example, if $Q(x)=0$, regardless of $P(x)$, the equation is separable.

Comment: Ah thank you, I knew I was missing something. So is this correct then?: If both P and Q are constant, or if at least one of them is $0$, or if P=Q, then the equation is separable?

Answer (score 0):

For linear ODEs of the form given above, the equation will not be separable in $x$ and $y$ variables, in general. It will hold only under special cases, like $P(x)=0$ or $Q(x)=0$ or, both of them being constants, or some other discrete conditions. But not always.

However, if you multiply both sides of the equation with $\exp \left(\int P(x) dx \right)$ and substitute $v=y\exp \left(\int P(x) dx \right)$, then the equation will $\textbf{always}$ be separable in $v$ and $x$, given that a finite antiderivative of $P(x)$ exists.

Comment: Thank you! What you mentioned in the second paragraph is called using the integration factor, right?

Comment: @JamesRonald Yes, you are right.